# Populating the array of text and value with an array of objects

Tags: angular

I am trying to populate an array of text and value with an array of object in angular. I have shared the JSOn that contains the array of objects.

Declaration

```
public AuditYearEnd: Array<{ text: string, value: number }>;
```

Assignment - How do I assign it here.

```
this.AuditYearEnd = this._fundTerms.AuditYearEndMonths;
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Text": "31 January",
    "Value": "1",
    "Selected": false
  },
  {
    "Text": "28 February",
    "Value": "2",
    "Selected": false
  },
  {
    "Text": "31 March",
    "Value": "3",
    "Selected": false
  },
  {
    "Text": "30 April",
    "Value": "4",
    "Selected": false
  },
  {
    "Text": "31 May",
    "Value": "5",
    "Selected": false
  },
  {
    "Text": "30 June",
    "Value": "6",
    "Selected": false
  },
  {
    "Text": "31 July",
    "Value": "7",
    "Selected": false
  },
  {
    "Text": "31 August",
    "Value": "8",
    "Selected": false
  },
  {
    "Text": "30 September",
    "Value": "9",
    "Selected": false
  },
  {
    "Text": "31 October",
    "Value": "10",
    "Selected": false
  },
  {
    "Text": "30 November",
    "Value": "11",
    "Selected": false
  },
  {
    "Text": "31 December",
    "Value": "12",
    "Selected": false
  }
]
```

Markup

```
   <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" class="form-control form-control-sm"  [(ngModel)]="auditYearEndSelected"
          data="AuditYearEnd"  [filterable]="false" textField="Text" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Value">
      </kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Component Code

```
get FundTerms(): any {
        return this._fundTerms;
    }

     @Input('FundTerms')
    set FundTerms(value: any) {
        this._fundTerms = value;
        if (this._fundTerms) {
         this.Fund = this._fundTerms.FundTermsDetailViewModel[0];
         this.AuditYearEnd = this._fundTerms.AuditYearEndMonths;
         this.isAgreement = this._fundTerms.FundTermsDetailViewModel[0].SideLetterAgreement;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I need AuditYearEnd should be an array of Text and Value. At the moment I am binding .AuditYearEnd  to kendodropdown control and getting error that data.map is not a function. The kendo-dropdown control is expecting an array. So I am trying to set AuditYearEnd  to an array

Comment: can you share both error and the code which is giving this error?

Comment: Have shared in the post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a silly mistake. You forget the square bracket for data attribute.

```
// put the square bracket for data attribute.
    <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" 
                        style="width:100%" 
                        class="form-control form-control-sm"  
                        [(ngModel)]="auditYearEndSelected"
                        [data]="AuditYearEnd"
                        [filterable]="false" textField="Text" 
                        [valuePrimitive]="true"
                        valueField="Value">
    </kendo-dropdownlist>
```